# Why can't I await calls to LambdaHelper.callAsync?

Tags: aws-lambda, async-await

I'm developing a vue.js application with node.js in the backend. The backend is also hosted by a lambda server on AWS.

On the backend, I'm trying to do the following:

```
    let success = false;
    let lh = new LambdaHelper();
    success = await lh.callAsync('MyController', 'myMethod', params);
```

This calls MyController.myMethod(params). But it doesn't await.

If I put a console log immediately after the call to lh.callAsync(...) and print out the value of success, it prints out undefined. And if I put some console logs in myMethod, it prints them out after it prints out the value of success. This means it is not awaiting the call to lh.callAsync(...).

Now if I replace the last line with...

```
    success = await require('MyController').myMethod(params)
```

...it works just fine (i.e. it awaits myMethod(...) and prints the value of success (true or false) after printing the console logs in myMethod(...)).

Is there a special trick to awaiting calls to methods through LambdaHelper.callAsync(...)? Thanks.

Comment: hard to say without looking at what LambdaHelper is doing. can you post the code?

Comment: My apologies. False alarm. LambdaHelper is one of ours after all. I thought it was an npm package. As soon as I realized that, I was able to solve the problem myself.